# 動的に追加した要素にswiper.jsが効かない

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, swiper

jQueryで動的に追加した要素に対してswiper.jsでスライドを実装したいのですが、機能しません。
動的に追加した要素に対しての処理であることが原因と考え、以下のようにswiperのオプションのobserverをtrueとしましたが、それによってTypeErrorとなります。
ご教授お願いいたします。

```
HTML記述
<div class="detail">
  <ul class="col-image-slide">
    <li>
      <img src="/album/sample.jpg" alt="サンプル">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

JS記述
$(document).ready(function() {
  var catalogSwiper = $('.detail').swiper({
    mode:'horizontal',
    loop: true,
    observer: true
  });
});

エラー
TypeError: Argument 1 of MutationObserver.observe is not an object.
```

Comment: @けーこ 様　いただいた情報を元に試しましたが、解消されず、別の要因が影響していると思われます。引き続き検証します。ありがとうございま‌​した。

Answer (score 1):

このエラーは MutationObserver.observe の第一引数がオブジェクトじゃないよ、つまり observe する要素がいないということです。
swiperのobserverはこのサンプルで言う div.detail に対してではなく ul.col-image-slide に対して行なってるようです。

たぶん以下のようなhtmlを用意して、swiperを初期化してるんじゃないでしょうか？

```
<div class="detail"></div>
```

以下のように ul.col-image-slide を含めたhtmlを用意して初期化すれば正常に動くと思います。

```
<div class="detail"><ul class="col-image-slide"></ul></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

swiperのデモ設置例に従い、HTMLとjsを下記の記述に修正したところ、機能しました。

```
HTML記述
<div class="detail swiper-container">
  <ul class="col-image-slide swiper-wrapper">
    <li class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="/album/sample.jpg" alt="サンプル">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

JS記述
$(document).ready(function() {
  var catalogSwiper = $('.swiper-container').swiper({
    mode:'horizontal',
    loop: true,
    observer: true
  });
});
```

swiper-container，swiper-wrapperなどのclass名が抜けていたことがエラーの要因のようでした。
liはswiper-slideというclassじゃなくても機能しましたが、ulにswiper-wrapperは必須のようでした。